# Code-signing certificate invalid for signing ClickOnce manifest

Tags: certificate, clickonce, code-signing

I have a .pfx that I want to use to sign my ClickOnce application. However, it tells me that the certificate is not valid for code signing. But when I go to my certmgr, it clearly states "Code Signing" as a value for "Enhanced Key Usage".
There is also a critical "Key Usage" field, and the value is only "Key Encipherment". Can someone tell me if these key usage values are enough to be able to sign ClickOnce applications? If they are, then what could cause the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, your certificate needs to contain digitalSignature in the keyUsage section. Otherwise ClickOnce may not be allowed to use the key to sign the ClickOnce manifest.